# How to decline a closed-group internal posting?

Tags: internal-transfer, correspondence

Someone was recently promoted on another team which left their old position available, and now it's currently up for grabs for a few individuals. On behalf of my previous manager, HR has sent an email to myself and several other coworkers (I don't know who or how many) to fill the position.

While I'm not interested in the position, should I respond to my manager thanking him for the offer? In my mind I liken it to someone holding up a box with the last doughnut in it and saying "Hey, Bob wants to know if anyone wants the last doughnut", and I feel would be weird to turn to Bob and say "No thanks, but I really appreciate the offer Bob!"

tl;dr Does this acknowledgement of my potential warrant a response?

Comment: It seems to me  that there are factors consider here that you may well want to take a close look at. So I ask: Does this other position have higher profile in the company? Would that position offer more pay? Does that role stretch your wings? Does it have better advancement potential?

Comment: They asked you a question "would you be interested in this position?" so you own them a reply. The reply is yours to chose as you see fit, but it would be very rude not to answer at all. Their next action depends on your reply and why would you make them wait for a "time out"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your analogy, it's even weirder if he holds up the box and ask people and no one so much as turns around to look at him.

A polite and professional reply will make it clear that you're not interested, and won't leave your boss wondering what's going on:

> Thank you for providing me with this opportunity, but I must respectfully decline. I am very happy with my current position, and wish to continue in this role.

I would argue that it's rude not to reply.

Answer (score 3):

Decline to HR including a "Thanks for considering me" with your boss CCed.  This makes your answer and your appreciation clear.

Answer (score 1):

The argument for replying: shows your boss you are in engaged in his communication, a very positive thing.

The argument against replying: he's gonna wonder why you don't want it, so I think you should justify perhaps why you don't, as your highlighting it. Or informally chat about it; make yourself prepared for that conversation. Some may say it's easier not to reply.

Decide which you would rather go for.

Perhaps by responding and having a conversation with him is a great channel for career discussion, which is good and gives him an idea of the sort of thing you are looking for. I think if you didn't want to reply, you wouldn't have asked the question, which ironically answers it for you!